# Unable to import a package located in the same directory

Tags: go

I want to import in the current file or package other file **located in the same project** in a directory. I'm doing this:

```
import (

// "./dir1"
  "/Users/my_name/my_project/dir1"

)
```

None of them works

```
  1) Cloning into '/Users/my_name/go/src/github.com/github_username/github_project'...
  fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled


  2) package /Users/my_name/my_project/dir1: unrecognized import path "/Users/my_name/my_project/dir1" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

How to import a directory located in the current project?

Comment: did you try adding a period in front of /Users/ to indicate that you're looking under the current directory?

Comment: Import is by *package name*, not by *path on disk*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename `dir1` to to the same name as the package inside that directory, then you can import it with:

```
import "./package1"
```

However doing this is not recommended, use [GOPATH](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/GOPATH) instead. If you really don't want to use GOPATH, you may want to use [Modules](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules) in Go 1.11 (but it is still experimental).

Answer (score 1):

Import paths are not directly paths. They are relative to the GOPATH (found by doing `echo $GOPATH`).

This implies that go is very opinionated about where you store your code as well. So you will have to move your code to `$GOPATH/src/my_name/my_project`. If you are hosting your code on something like github then move it to `$GOPATH/src/github.com/my_github_name/my_project`.

Then when you import your sub-packages:

```
import "github.com/my_github_name/my_project"
```

Notice that it is not an absolute path.

Comment: I don't want to move it anywhere. Other options?

Comment: You could make s symlink, but be aware you are swimming upstream a little. Its fairly common for a language to have an opinion on where you place your code.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project is in GOPATH's *go/src* folder(Recommended way). Then import like this

```
package logic

import (
    "project_name/folder_name"
)
```